# How to Get the File Extension from IFromFile MicorsoftAspNetCore

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to get the simple file extension for example "XLSX","pdf" and so on instead of the whole raw `Content-type` when I use `IFromFile.ContenType` gives me the raw `content-type` header on  the uploaded file, any help is really appreciated

Comment: How come I could type "iformfile" into the Microsoft Docs search box to see a list of properties of this type to get an answer to your question but you couldn't? You could have used the F1 key to get to the same page or even just used Intellisense to see what properties there were and what they contained at run time.

Comment: @John I've come to the conclusion that most people don't try the docs before posting.

Comment: @John I search :) and the properties only get only mimeType which is the thing I don't want, please be helpful instead of being mean to other people :)

Comment: That is blatantly untrue. The [`FileName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile.filename?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-http-iformfile-filename) property, which you would have found if you did as I described, gives you the information you want. I use that property in my own code and someone else has mentioned it in an answer. If you want to be able to develop software then it's assumed that you can read the official documentation. To point that out is not mean. If you can't do the basics, you need to improve.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar, I agree, but every time it happens it should be pointed out that ignoring the official Help when you want help is wrong. RTFM is a cliché for a reason. Look first, ask questions later. That should be obvious.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For getting file extension from uploaded file (IFormFile), Use:

```
System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for the extension type, Use

```
var extension = Path.GetExtension(Server.MapPath("file.txt"));
```

For the Mime type

```
var mimeType  = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping("file.txt");
```